# Error in dependencies voxel_grid

Tags: ros, navigation, rosdep, rosdep-install, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I make `rosdep check costmap_2d`
i get this error :

```
 System dependencies have not been satisified:
apt ros-groovy-map-msgs
ERROR[costmap_2d]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [voxel_grid]
    rosdep key : voxel_grid
    OS name    : ubuntu
    OS version : precise
    Data: <no data>
```

Howerver, i already have created a package voxel_grid, which had any error.
I really don't know what to do
I'm using groovy (Ubuntu 12.04)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187516/error-in-dependencies-voxel_grid/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-23**:
Hi, did you put voxel grid in pacake.xml and cmakelists ?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-23**:
Yes I have

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-23**:
Is it same build as you are trying in other question, I mean same package or different. If different please post package.xml and cmakelist

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-23**:
It is the same package but I'm trying to solve two issues : one is that the pcl/conversions.h is not found the second is that the voxel_grid dependencies is not satisfied, that why I posted two question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean you "created a package voxel_grid"?

Are you executing the `rosdep check` command in a shell where you have sourced the setup file for groovy (`source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash`)?

Is rosdep cache up to date? (`rosdep update`)

**EDIT:** You cannot depend on `voxel_grid` from a catkin package in groovy, since it is a dry (= rosbuild) package and catkin packages cannot depend on rosbuild packages. In hydro, voxel_grid is a catkin package and this error should not occur.

If you must use groovy and you must depend on `voxel_grid`, then you should build your package with rosbuild, not catkin. Maybe it is possible to install a catkinized navigation stack (of which voxel_grid is a part) from source ontop of your groovy installtion, but it might not even work at all without major tweaks.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-23**:
I'm executing rosdep in my workspace /catkin_ws
I created a package with catkin_create_pkg
Yes I already launched rosdep update

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-23**:
So `voxel_grid` is part of the navigation stack, which on groovy is a `dry` package (i.e. rosbuild, not catkin). That means you cannot build a catkin package that does depend on it. @William: Is this actually the cause of the error, or is something funky going on with the release status of the navig

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-23**:
ation stack on groovy? Should `rosinstall_generator voxel_grid --rosdistro groovy` work or does that only work for stacks with dry packages, @Dirk Thomas? (I noticed `rosinstall_generator navigation --rosdistro groovy` still works).

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-07-23**:
He said he created a package called `voxel_grid`, could the problem be that there is already a package called `voxel_grid`? http://wiki.ros.org/voxel_grid?distro=groovy

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-23**:
Unless he has built and sourced the workspace, the package is not going to be picked up. I tested depending on `voxel_grid` from a catkin package and get the same error with rosdep and rosdistro groovy. voxel_grid is dry, so maybe that is expected (although the msg is hardly useful in that case).